# How to resolve email error relaying denied, but not trying to relay?

Tags: email, email-headers, email-bounces

I've written a PHP application that includes a bulk mailing feature. It uses Zend Framework's SMTP transport class to send the emails. Each email is sent as an individual email using our own SMTP server, for which we have to authenticate.

We tested our first mass mailing today. I'm seeing a lot of bounce messages where the error message is some variation of *relaying denied*. But I don't understand how/where the relaying is happening. The majority of the messages are reaching their destinations.

I understand what relaying is and how most servers block it. But I don't understand why it's happening in this case. The error message is generated by the recipient mail server, not the server we are sending through/from.

I've tried a variety of searches, but nothing addresses this situation. I'm at a complete loss on what to try.

**Here's one:**

```
Final-Recipient: rfc822; info@recipient.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;info@recipient.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Remote-MTA: dns; mail.recipient.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 5.7.1 <info@recipient.com>: Relay access
    denied
Return-Path: <bounces@ourdomain.com>
Received: from localhost (ourdomain.com [xx.xx.xx.xx])
    by server.ourdomain.net (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 555EE1A40A40
    for <info@recipient.com>; Wed,  3 Jul 2013 14:30:03 -0400 (EDT)
Date: Wed, 03 Jul 2013 18:30:03 +0000
To: info@recipient.com
From: Jane Doe <profiles@ourdomain.com>
Reply-To: profiles@ourdomain.com
X_Id: 155:20130703183003+0000:info@recipient.com
Subject: Update Your Complimentary Listing - Acme Widgets Ltd.
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="=_c7534a079bebc99232f7fc965e3ce207"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Message-Id: <20130703183003.555EE1A40A40@server.ourdomain.net>
```

**And another:**

```
Final-Recipient: rfc822; john.smith@recipient.ca
Original-Recipient: rfc822;john.smith@recipient.ca
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Remote-MTA: dns; mail.recipient.ca
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.7.1 <john.smith@recipient.ca>... Relaying
    denied. Proper authentication required.
Return-Path: <bounces@ourdomain.com>
Received: from localhost (ourdomain.com [xx.xx.xx.xx])
    by server.ourdomain.net (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 2E8161A40A57
    for <john.smith@recipient.ca>; Wed,  3 Jul 2013 17:30:05 -0400 (EDT)
Date: Wed, 03 Jul 2013 21:30:05 +0000
To: john.smith@recipient.ca
From: Jane Doe <profiles@ourdomain.com>
Reply-To: profiles@ourdomain.com
X_Id: 2590:20130703213005+0000:john.smith@recipient.ca
Subject: Update Complimentary Listing - Acme Canada Inc.
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="=_6e8e745d73ac533aa878237363777974"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Message-Id: <20130703213005.2E8161A40A57@server.ourdomain.net>
```

Comment: post a few examples of full headers of failed messages (excluding private details)